# Displaying object details in a ListView in Android

Tags: android, class, listview, android-arrayadapter

As part of an Activity, I have a class encapsulating functionality for a single object and want to display details of the object in a `ListView` when a particular button is pressed.

**Attempt One:**

If I pass the `ListView` and `this` to the object to store (!) and then try to call the `ArrayAdapter`, I get a runtime error:

> Source not found

Code segment (method within the class)...

```
private void displayTouch(Touch lasttouch) {

    String mLine = "";
    /* Build up line of analysis */
    ...
    /* Display line */
    mAnalysis[lasttouch.mSequence] = mLine;
    mViewAnalysis.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>     (mActivity,R.layout.simplerow,mAnalysis));
} // End of method displayTouch
```

**Attempt Two**

If I try to display data in the `ListView` from within the `OnClick` Listener, I get an error message in Eclipse:

> The constructor ArrayAdapter (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, String[] is undefined.

Code segment (within the OnClick Listener of the Activity)...

```
/* Record details */
OnClickListener CourtListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        /* Analyse  */
        ...
        /* Capture  analysis */
            lRoster.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.simplerow,playerArray)); 
        } // End of event onClick 
    }; // End of listener CourtListener
```

In this code `playerArray` is dimensioned within the Activity's `onCreate`;

Both attempts have weaknesses of approach (in addition to not working) so I'll re-factor once I can get something working.

Essentially, how do I display data generated within an object to a `ListView` within an Activity from the `OnClick` Listener of another View in the same Activity?  Everything is within one package and within the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this blogpost might help: [Putting custom objects in ListView](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/)